# python efficient if statements conditions

Tags: python, if-statement

I created a sample program for 3 data points however, I have many data points and need more efficient code to run. The logic is I am comparing every Pi with its next P(i+1) and post comparing all the differences, I am selecting the max value and taking its relevant BSPi & SSPi.
additional condition is if P[i] is greater than p[i+1]; it should be greater than 50.

```
sp1=100
sp2=150
sp3=200
sp4=250

p1=90
p2=40
p3=120
p4=150


if p1-p2>=0:
    d1=p1-p2-50
    bsp1=sp2
    ssp1=sp1
else:
    d1=p2-p1
    bsp1=sp1
    ssp1=sp2



if p2-p3>=0:
    d2=p2-p3-50
    bsp2=sp3
    ssp2=sp2
else:
    d2=p3-p2
    bsp2=sp2
    ssp2=sp3



if p3-p4>=0:
    d3=p3-p4-50
    bsp3=sp4
    ssp3=sp3
else:
    d3=p4-p3
    bsp3=sp3
    ssp3=sp3

data = {'d1': d1,'d2': d2, 'd3': d3,}
max_data=max(data, key=data.get)
if max_data=='d1':
    bsp=bsp1
    ssp=ssp1
elif max_data=='d2':
    bsp=bsp2
    ssp=ssp2
else:
    bsp=bsp3
    ssp=ssp3

print(bsp)
print(ssp)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? Do you mean you want the code to run faster? Or that you don't want to spend time writing so much code? Don't worry about how fast your code is yet. For writing less code, I suggest you learn about lists and loops.

Comment: Yeah I meant the list and loop functions would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array to contain `sp = [sp1, ... , spn]`
Create an array to contain `p = [p1, ... , pn]`
Initialize a value `max = 0`
Initialize a value `index = 0`

Iterate through range of `p` (given that `len(p) > 1`), calculate the difference of `i` and `i+1` elements. If the difference is greater than max, store the difference and store the index.

In the end, store into `bsp = sp[index]` and `ssp = sp[index+1]`

```
def find_max_in_data(p, sp):
    max_diff = 0
    index = 0

    for i in range(len(p)-1):
        diff = abs(p[i+1] - p[i])
        if diff > max_diff:
            max_diff = diff
            index = i
    
    ssp = sp[index]
    bsp = sp[index+1]
```

EDIT: For more particular code,

```
def find_max_in_data(p, sp):
    max_diff = 0
    bspindex = 0
    sspindex = 0

    for i in range(len(p)-1):
        if p[i] - p[i+1] >= 0:
            diff = p[i] - p[i+1] - 50
            if diff > max_diff:
                max_diff = diff
                bspindex = i+1
                sspindex = i
        else:
            diff = p[i+1] - p[i]
            if diff > max_diff:
                max_diff = diff
                bspindex = i
                sspindex = i+1
    
    ssp = sp[sspindex]
    bsp = sp[bspindex]
```

Comment: in this, if p[i]-p[i+1]>=0 then diff=p[i]-p[i+1]-50. is missing. where should i add that condition?

Comment: @RakeshMulik please review my edit and let me know if that addresses your concerns.

Comment: Oh yes, it is working on the sample data. let me run on the larger set. Will update u. And thanks a ton. Since I am a self-taught python learner its all amazing to me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach.

Rather than defining many discrete variables, write a class that incorporates all of the associated variables for a "data point". Something like this (with full property, str and repr functionality):

```
class DataPoint:
    def __init__(self, p, sp):
        self._p = p
        self._sp = sp
        self._ssp = None
        self._bsp = None
        self._d = None
    @property
    def p(self):
        return self._p
    @property
    def sp(self):
        return self._sp
    @property
    def ssp(self):
        return self._ssp
    @ssp.setter
    def ssp(self, v):
        self._ssp = v
    @property
    def bsp(self):
        return self._bsp
    @bsp.setter
    def bsp(self, v):
        self._bsp = v
    @property
    def d(self):
        return self._d
    @d.setter
    def d(self, v):
        self._d = v
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.p=} {self.sp=} {self.ssp=} {self.bsp=} {self.d=}'
    def __str__(self):
        return f'p={self.p}, sp={self.sp}, ssp={self.ssp}, bsp={self.bsp}, d={self.d}'
```

Using this structure you can build a list of classes like this:

```
data_points = []

data_points.append(DataPoint(90, 100))
data_points.append(DataPoint(40, 150))
data_points.append(DataPoint(120, 200))
data_points.append(DataPoint(150, 250))
```

Note how the *p* and *sp* values relate to the ones in the question.

Now that we have a list of these classes we can write a single piece of code to process them and populate them with appropriate values.

```
for dpa, dpb in zip(data_points, data_points[1:]):
    if dpa.p - dpb.p >= 0:
        dpa.d = dpa.p - dpb.p - 50
        dpa.bsp = dpb.sp
        dpa.ssp = dpa.sp
    else:
        dpa.d = dpb.p - dpa.p
        dpa.bsp = dpa.sp
        dpa.ssp = dpb.sp
    print(dpa)
```

This gives the following output:

```
p=90, sp=100, ssp=100, bsp=150, d=0
p=40, sp=150, ssp=200, bsp=150, d=80
p=120, sp=200, ssp=250, bsp=200, d=30
```

Note that there are just 3 outputs. This is as expected due to the way the comparisons are carried out.

Comment: I am actually new to python  but ur code gave me an idea as to how i can take live figures into data base and calculate diff... Thanks a lot